# Change drop-down labels for Django UserAdmin

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I have a `User` model with a `timezone` field on it:

```py
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    timezone = models.CharField(
        max_length=64,
        choices=[(tz, tz) for tz in pytz.common_timezones],
        default="UTC",
    )
```

When viewed in Django admin, this creates a drop-down list of timezones, but only of the names. I would like to dynamically generate labels for this drop-down that add the offset as a prefix (e.g. `+02:00`) and sort the list by that. I know I can create these by doing something like:

```py
choices=[
    (tz, display_with_offset(tz))
    for tz in pytz.common_timezones
],
```

where `display_with_offset` generates the required label, but I think this would only calculate it when the migrations are run and would ignore any daylight savings changes that happen throughout the year for some regions.

My admin file looks like this:

```py
class MyUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    fieldsets = [
        ("Info", {"fields": ("timezone")}),
    ]

admin.site.register(models.User, MyUserAdmin)
```

Is there a way I can dynamically set the drop-down labels?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a ModelForm and override the choices. For example:

```
class UserAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
      super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
      self.fields['timezone'].choices = [
          (tz, display_with_offset(tz)) for tz in pytz.common_timezones
      ]

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = '__all__'

class MyUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    fieldsets = [
        ("Info", {"fields": ("timezone")}),
    ]
    form = UserAdminForm
```

More information can be found in [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.form).

Comment: Legend. _Thank you_. Also just as a heads up there are a couple of typos in your answer (a colon after the `super()__init__(...)` line and `,choices` instead of `.choices`.

Comment: Note that you don't need to this in the `__init__()` method, `choices` can be a callable when you define a form field. So you could also have defined `timezone = forms.ChoiceField(choices=timezone_choices)` to override `timezone` in the form, where `timezone_choices` is a function that returns your list of choices.